# How can I customize error messages of Cerberus?

Tags: python, cerberus

I want to localize the error messages Cerberus returns, e.g. I'd like to achieve the following:

```
>>> validator.schema = {'animal': {'forbidden': ['Einhorn']}}
>>> validator({'animal': 'Einhorn'})
False
>>> validator.errors
{'animal': ['VERBOTEN!']}  # instead of 'unallowed value Einhorn'
```

Answer (score 11):

You can simply subclass the default error handler `BasicErrorhandler` from the `cerberus.errors` module and adjust the message templates as you like:

```
>>> class CustomErrorHandler(errors.BasicErrorHandler):
...     messages = errors.BasicErrorHandler.messages.copy()
...     messages[errors.FORBIDDEN_VALUE.code] = 'VERBOTEN!'
...     
>>> validator = Validator(schema, error_handler=CustomErrorHandler)
>>> validator({'animal': 'Einhorn'})
False
>>> validator.errors
{'animal': ['VERBOTEN!']}
```

Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus/blob/master/cerberus/errors.py) for available error codes and template variables.