# Cerberus META validation rule access

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

Python [cerberus](https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus) has a validation rule called [meta](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#meta) where I assign a dict to meta rule. How am i supposed to access it? I am writing a custom error_handler using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47730455/4644332) to customise the error messages.

My target is `schema = {'a': {'type': 'integer', 'meta': {'label': 'Age'}}}`
and would like to use the label in my error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i don't have the time for a detailed answer, but if you want to access the `schema` property of a validator from the error handler, you'll have to bind the validator to some property of the handler first. probably in `_format_message`, you can then resolve to the `meta` rule in the schema with `error.schema_path`.

Comment: @yugantar, did you find a way to access the `label` in your error messages? I have a similar situation as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56936542/1082673) and I can't seem to figure out how to do that

Comment: Hi @lukik , I have answered my own question and also added an answer to your question of how I got around this use case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I created a custom error_handler to prepend the label to my error messages.

```
from cerberus.errors import BasicErrorHandler

class CustomErrorHandler(BasicErrorHandler):
    def __init__(self, schema):
        self.custom_defined_schema = schema

    def _format_message(self, field, error):
        return self.custom_defined_schema[field].get('meta', {}).get('label', field) + ': ' + super(CustomErrorHandler, self)._format_message(field, error)

val = Validator(schema, error_handler=CustomErrorHandler(schema))
```

Hopefully it'll help the future users.