# How do I return a custom rule-name/error-code using Cerberus?

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

Am validating `.csv` file and I want to give the results of the validation in a format the user is accustomed to. To make use of [Cerberus](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/index.html), I've let the user to define the validation rules in a `.yaml` file.

**schema.yaml**

```
Rules:
 Rule1:
  maxlength: 10

 Rule2:
  allowed: ["MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA", "SU"]

 Rule3:
  required: True
```

I have then mapped those rules to the columns in the CSV file where they apply.

**csv_fields.yaml**

```
Fields:
 1:
  rules:
   - Rule1
   - Rule2

 2:
  rules:
   - Rule2
   - Rule3

 3:
  rules:
   - Rule1
   - Rule3
```

**sample_file.csv**

Below is a sample file that has three columns: `first_name`, `day_of_week` and `is_employed`.

```
Peter, XX, True
```

To validate using Cerberus, am cross referencing the `rules` defined in the `rules` key of the `csv_fields.yaml` document with the `Rules` in the `schema.yaml` file. This is easy to do as `.yaml` files are read as dictionaries in python in a key-value format.

**My Problem**

In the above sample data, cerberus with throw the error `'day_of_week': ['unallowed value XX']` but a user won't know what rule triggered this error.

What am looking forward to tell the user is that the error `unallowed value XX` was triggered by `Rule2` as the user knows `Rule2` rather than the technical Cerberus specific definition.

Is there a way to achieve this even if it means defining the `schema.yaml` differently?

I've looked at the [Cerberus Errors Section](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/errors.html) but can't seem to find a way to do this.

**Update:**

So I've tried adding a `meta` field to the rule definition in **schema.yaml**

```
Rules:
 Rule1:
  maxlength: 10
  meta: {'rule_name': "Rule1"}
```

But when I test, I can't seem to access this Meta Key from the Error raised as I can't find it in `document_error_tree` or even `schema_error_tree`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was at the same space as you are, I'll tell you what I did.

Created a custom error_handler and prepend the error messages with human readable keys.

```
from cerberus.errors import BasicErrorHandler

class CustomErrorHandler(BasicErrorHandler):
        def __init__(self, schema):
            self.custom_defined_schema = schema

        def _format_message(self, field, error):
            return self.custom_defined_schema[field].get('meta', {}).get('rule_name', field) + ': ' + super(CustomErrorHandler, self)._format_message(field, error)

val = Validator(schema, error_handler=CustomErrorHandler(schema))
```

This is what I did, hopefully it can be of use to you.

Comment: This does exactly what my **update** section wanted to accomplish (and in a way it will solve my initial question). Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. If you could just accept the answer, it can help the future readers :)

Comment: @yugantar can you give an example of a schema with meta that this code would work with?